# Is a summer REU considered OPT/CPT training for F-1 visa?

Tags: f1-visa

I am a student under F-1 visa in the US. I was offered a paid Research Experience for Undergraduates (REU) program for the upcoming summer 2017 from a different school. Is the REU considered Optional Practical Training/Curriculum Practical Training (OPT/CPT)?

Comment: If you would spell out the abbreviations, that would be helpful.

Comment: I found a university website that for an REU you would need work authorization and that you would have to apply for OPT or CPT. You should talk to the international student office at your university. Or see if the REU program has information.

Comment: You are more likely to find someone knowledgeable about F-1 visas and related training programs at [Expatriates.SE].