# Is Research Experiences for Undergraduates (REU) classified as an internship or as professional training under US law?

Tags: united-states

How does US law define "internship" and "professional training"? In particular, are [US REU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Research_Experiences_for_Undergraduates) programs considered to be internships or professional training programs?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on https://academia.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @BlueDogRanch I don't see how a question about the US law would be on-topic for Academia SE.

Comment: There are 627 questions tagged REU: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reu and only two on Law SE.

Comment: @BlueDogRanch And your point is? This question is still not on-topic on Academia. The relative number of questions is immaterial.

Comment: Related: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/16990/is-a-summer-reu-considered-opt-cpt-training-for-f-1-visa   I've found several sites that say that if any support is provided (even room/board), you need OPT or CPT authorization.

Comment: @mkennedy I'd be paying in full for my food/accommodation and wouldn't be receiving any kind of payment from the university, so I guess OPT/CPT authorization isn't relevant to my case (as an international student).

Comment: @S.D. You should definitely go to your university's international office and ask them.

Comment: @mkennedy Well, yes. I've already sent an email to the international office. Meanwhile, I'm trying to determine what the US official regulations say.